# Same s.no but length is different want to highlight maxs length of Same serial no in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

A column contains S.no, B column contains Length, In c column i want maximum length in b column which is having same serial no.
For eg:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried so far to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=REPT("MAX",MAX(($A$2:$A$16=A2)*$B$2:$B$16)=B2)
```

---

Or, if you want to display the max number for each sl.no then

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=REPT(B2,MAX(($A$2:$A$16=A2)*$B$2:$B$16)=B2)
```

---

Comment: Thanks Mayukh Bhattacharya, It works Perfect

Answer (score 0):

My approach to ans your question..

[image: Result]

```
=IF(MAXIFS($B$2:$B$16,$A$2:$A$16,A2)=B2,"Max","")
```